# open a window on the same page after clicking a link

Tags: javascript, html, css

suppose i click a link. How can i open a window over same page. I don't want a new tab or window.... just clicking a link should open something there only
I don't want to use target_bank as it opens in new tab. My window should be something as it appears just above the link. To be  more specific if i go to www.talkingtextbook.in and suppose i click any link a window appears over the same page. Please help me how can i do this

would this method help??

```
window.open("www.youraddress.com","_self")
```

Comment: have you tried `window.location.href = "www.youraddress.com"` ?

Comment: It's not link, it looks like any lightbox or something similar. See that you have still the same URL, there is no refresh (no link used), etc. You the hash in URL is changed (`location.hash`).

Comment: After skimming through the source code it looks like they're using modal windows. I believe modal windows are what you're looking for.

Comment: your question is pretty unclear, you say that you want to open a window on a same page and again you are saying that you don't to open a new window or tab.

Comment: It's a modal window and when you click the "continue reading" link a style is applied so that the model window fills the screen.

Comment: You want to open the window or need to redirect to page?

Comment: he says that he want to open a window in the same page, not a new page in the same window.

Comment: @Newinjava Guess he will need to use iframe or .load() function in jquery for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

Try

> onClick="window.location='www.youraddress.com'"

It will Open new url on same windows

Comment: he says that he want to open a window in the same page, not a new page in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes
We can do like using anchor.
For eg:
Suppose this is menu link

```
<a href="#sample1">Menu</a>
```

and content div is:

```
<div id="sample1">Content</div>
```

Like that we can add for another items
For pop up to occur need to add like "a" tag onclick and we can use that show/hide using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use js to open a modal or lightbox plugin and skin the modal/lightbox to be 100% in width and height via css

Based on the page you shared you can set up the modal like this

on your html

```
...
<body>
    your content <a href="#" id="open-modal-1">open modal 1</a>
    <div class="modal" id="modal-1">
        the modal content
    </div>
</body>
...
```

On your js

```
var trigger = document.getElementById('open-modal-1'),
    modal = document.getElementById('modal-1');

trigger.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     if (modal.style.display == 'block'){
          modal.style.display = 'none';
     }else{
          modal.style.display = 'block';
     }
}, true);
```

on your css

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
}
```

Comment: @SinghRajputKushagra  perhaps a google search for "jquery modal plugin" would point you in the right direction. Also please remember to mark as correct the answer that fixed your issue for the community.

Answer (score 0):

> Please try this.

```
window.open("", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
```

> The first parameter in window.open , i left empty. you can specify URl
> to show that page. or what ever you need.( you form etc).
>
> top -> it specify the position where you want to show new window on
> same page.